# How to transform grouping with MAX from sql to linq query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am stuck trying to convert below sql query to linq:

```
SELECT
    Table1.Id1,
    Table2.Id2,
    MAX(Table3.DateField) AS MaxDateField
FROM
    Table1 
INNER JOIN
    Table2 ON Table1.Id1 = Table2.FK1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Table3 ON Table2.Id2 = Table3.FK2
GROUP BY 
    Table1.Id1, Table2.Id2
```

Table1/Table2 relationship is 1 to many, and Table2/Table3 is also 1 to many.

The SQL works properly and delivers only one record from Table3 for each Table1 and Table2 record.

For linq I tried:

```
var query = from table1 in tables1
            join table2 in tables2 on table1.Id1 equals table2.FK1
            join table3 in tables3 on table2.Id2 equals table3.FK2 into JoinedTable3Table2
            from table3 in JoinedTable3Table2.DefaultIfEmpty()

            group new {
                 table3.MyDateField
            }
            by new  {
                 table1.Id1,
                 table2.Id2,
                 table3.MyDateField
            }
            into g    
            select new MyModel {
                 Field1 = g.Key.Id1,
                 Field2 = g.Key.Id2,
                 Field3 = g.Max(d => d.MyDateField)
            };
```

But this returns n records from Table3 for each record in Table1 and Table2.

Then I tried (as Svyatoslav Danyliv suggested):

```
var query = from table1 in tables1
            join table2 in tables2 on table1.Id1 equals table2.FK1
            join table3 in tables3 on table2.Id2 equals table3.FK2 into JoinedTable3Table2
            from table3 in JoinedTable3Table2.DefaultIfEmpty()

            group new {
                 table1.Id1,
                 table2.Id2
            }
            by new  {
                 table1.Id1,
                 table2.Id2,
                 table3.MyDateField
            }
            into g    
            select new MyModel {
                 Field1 = g.Key.Id1,
                 Field2 = g.Key.Id2,
                 Field3 = g.Max(d => d.MyDateField) 
            };
```

But then I get an error at `Field3 = g.Max(d => d.MyDateField)` (CS 1061:anonymous type)

Answer (score 1):

You have difference in grouping fields `table3.MyDateField` is wrong.
Also if your model has proper navigation properties, your query can be simplified.

```cs
var query = from table1 in tables1
            from table2 in table1.Table2s 
            from table3 in table2.Table3s 

            group table3
            by new  {
                 table1.Id1,
                 table2.Id2
            }
            into g    
            select new MyModel {
                 Field1 = g.Key.Id1,
                 Field2 = g.Key.Id2,
                 Field3 = g.Max(d => d.MyDateField)
            };
```

Comment: I have navigation properties for Table1, Table2 and Table3 and your approach works. But my sample is a simplified version.
I also need to join some additional tables to table2 via 'left outer join' (i.e.  ...DefaultIfEmpty()) in order to get properties from these tables.
How can I join these additional tables using your approach?

Comment: Yes, you can do joins. You just had wrong GroupBy key.

Comment: Yes, I corrected the error. But I need to make additional joins (see my comment above), to tables where I do not have navigation properies set up. How would I join to these tables?

Comment: I didn't get problem. Add joins as in your original question. It is correct. If there is no navigation properties - use `join` operator.

Comment: Checked updated question. `group` is wrong, `by` is wrong. Check my sample how to group

Answer (score 0):

If your model is correctly defined, you don't really need to do joins in LINQ.

See if this query works

```
var results = context.tables2.Select(row => new 
        { row.FK1, row.ID2, MaxDate = row.LinkedEntities.Max(e => e.MyDateField) }));
```

This will require you to define `LinkedEntities` as a navigation property for 1-* relationship between tables 2 and 3.

Comment: What do you mean by 'if your model is correctly defined' ?  I am working on an mvc project on an api controller that fetches entities via UnitOfWork. The used model in the controller is a C# class with no navigation properties, just { get; set; } statements for the properties.

Comment: I should have said "completely" rather than correctly. :) EF without proper navigation properties and FKs, and LINQ which has explicit joins, `Include()`s and `group by` in most cases is an indication that the feature set EF provides is not being used completely.

Comment: In case you meant the model of the database: Navigation properties such as Table1.Tables2 ... is definded

Comment: I get it to work for collecting records from Table1, Table2 and Table3. But I  I need some other properties from 2 other tables that I have to join, but do not have navigation properties for. I do have keys to to make a 'left outer join'. How could I achieve that?

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from adding the navigation properties which would be needed? That's the cleanest way forward imo.

Comment: I have navigation properties for Table1, Table2 and Table3, but I am not able to add navigation properties for Table2/Table4 (can't get it to work). Since Table4 has some properties that I need in the query I am stuck with the linq join (which I got to work).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Badar's and Danyliv's help I found a working solution.

I need to mention that the sample I posted was a simplified version. I also need to join  table2 to a 4th Table (Table4) via a 'left outer join' in order to get properties from Table4 (where navigation properties are not set up) but matching keys are available.

```
var query = from table1 in tables1
            join table2 in tables2 on table1.Id1 equals table2.FK1

            join table4 in tables4 on table2.Id2 equals table4.FK2 into JoinedTable4Table2
            from table4 in JoinedTable4Table2.DefaultIfEmpty()

            join table3 in tables3 on table2.Id2 equals table3.FK2 into JoinedTable3Table2
            from table3 in JoinedTable3Table2.DefaultIfEmpty()

            group table3 // needed to be changed
            by new {
                 table1.Id1,
                 table2.Id2,
                 table4.Id4,
                 // any other field, but no field from table3
                 // table3.MyDateField // had to be removed!!
            }
            into g    
            select new MyModel {
                 Field1 = g.Key.Id1,
                 Field2 = g.Key.Id2,
                 Field4 = g.Key.Id4,
                 Field3 = g.Max(d => d.MyDateField)
                 //... 
            };
```